# SQL Select All Columns Where Field 'A' is Unique

Tags: sql, jpa

I am using a Java Spring JPA framework and I have the following table:

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | userID  | creditID  |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 | 1       | 1         |
|  2 | 1       | 2         |
|  3 | 1       | 3         |
|  4 | 2       | 4         |
|  5 | 1       | 1         |
|  6 | 1       | 2         |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

I want to query based on `userID` to obtain the most recent and unique `creditIDs`.  I have most recently tried the query `"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE user_id = 'userId' GROUP BY credit_id"`, where I get `runtime errors` because of my `group by` statement.

What would be the simplest syntax to achieve the following results?

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | userID  | creditID  |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  3 | 1       | 3         |
|  5 | 1       | 1         |
|  6 | 1       | 2         |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for your Question

```
  SELECT id, user_id, distinct(creditID) FROM Table WHERE user_id = 1
```

Comment: I tried something similar to that before, I am wondering if DISTINCT is not supported by the framework I am using.  I get the following error: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: Syntax error: Encountered "distinct" at line 1, column 12.

Comment: Please check your syntax. I am very surprised that it is giving you any error.
Group by and distinct is very common commands, so it should work. I think the problem is in column names or something

Answer (score 1):

Use `select` and filter in the `where`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.userid = t.userid and t2.creditid = t.creditid) and
      t.userid = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, userid, DISTINCT(creditid) FROM table WHERE userid = 'required user id';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.